# Using Git in Windows Subsystem for Linux through IntelliJ

Tags: batch-file, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set Git executable in IntelliJ to be the git installed in Windows Subsystem for Linux, I tried a few different ways, but always got some sort of error. Today I installed to Creators Update (Version 1703), reinstalled WSL and tried again, here's what I did:

I created a .bat script:

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "git %*"
```

So when running it:

```
C:\Users\Limon\Desktop>bash.bat --version
git version 2.7.4
```

So then I tried to set this bat at the git executable in IntelliJ:
[image: Setting Git executable in IntelliJ]

And it worked! But everything else fails, for example when I try to pull or branch in IntelliJ, I get:

```
Couldn't check the working tree for unmerged files because of an error.
'C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any ideas on how fix this? I don't really know anything about batch scripting. It works perfectly off command line.

Answer (score 22):

I was looking for a way to use git on WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux through Webstorm or an IntelliJ idea software.

I tried KatoPue's solution, but I got the following error:

`fatal: could not read log file 'C:/Program Files/Git/mnt/c/Users/Elies/AppData/Local/Temp/git-commit-msg-.txt': No such file or directory`

I solved it by replacing the path when sending the command to WSL's git

```
Settings > Version Control > Git > Path to Git executable : path_to_wslgit.bat
```

wslgit.bat :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=%*
set find=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt
set replace=/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Temp/git-commit-msg-.txt
call set command=%%command:!find!=!replace!%%
echo | C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
```

Comment: When I try this, the command never returns from intellij; it just hangs forever. Running it on command line works fine, though (as `git.bat config --list`, for instance). Also, the `%string%` var wasn't defined, leading to "echo is off" in the log file. I tried adding `--no-pager` to the git command on the last line, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ah, got it. You can fix this by piping an empty string to bash.exe: `echo | bash.exe ...`

Comment: This answer worked for me on VS Code just fine! Kudos and thank yous all around!

Comment: If you get an error "\bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." then try `C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe` .

Comment: When I use this I get the error `could not read log file 'C:UsersNameAppDataLocalTempgit-commit-msg-.txt': No such file or directory`, apparently all the slashes are getting removed somehow.

Comment: As mentioned by @mfuesslin, also check in `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`.

Answer (score 19):

Since **[WebStorm 2020.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/)** it is possible.

Just add `\\wsl$\YOUR-WSL-VERSION\usr\bin\git` to the **Path to Git executable**:

[image]

To get your `WSL VERSION` type in a console `wsl -l`

Comment: This is fab! Scrolling to the bottom paid off :D

Comment: when i click test instead of the git version i get a prompt that git isn't installed, with a popup after i click on it to downgrade git for windows to 2.24.1.2 and then git for windows is set as my git again

Comment: @notacorn Which version of WebStorm do you have installed?

Comment: i have intellij 2020.1.4 installed so thats probably my problem @Gabrielizalo now waiting on lombok

Comment: @notacorn I had the same problem with PyCharm. But I just updated path to Git executable, and with Test button I got an error. I just ignore it. And it works anyway.

Comment: This also works in PhpStorm since [2020.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/06/intellij-idea-2020-2-eap3-support-for-git-installed-in-wsl2-java-completion-improvements-and-more/)

Comment: This also works in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Ultimate Edition) !
In my case, I had to enter **\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\git** for the path even though I have _Ubuntu 20.04 LTS_ version installed.

Answer (score 11):

In PyCharm 2018.1 I got various errors, when trying to settled up Git. I've to combine different approaches to make it run. Next code works for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=%*
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
    echo | C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
) Else (
    echo | bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
)
```

UPD:

Now is available integration with Git inside WSL through WSLGit wrapper. I've checket it out with PyCharm and it's work like a charm. Here is a link https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit

Comment: https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit worked for me on with WSL 2 and PhpStorm 2019.3. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

Change the double to single quotes.

You can log, what arguments are fed to your bat file

```
@echo off
@echo %*>> %~dp0log.txt
bash.exe -c 'git %*'
```

With that, i discovered i had some escaping problems.

FYI: With the Win10 creators update piping bash and spawning it from Windows programs works fine.

Answer (score 4):

In PhpStorm (2017.2 EAP) I get error

> Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException: 'bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

For solution i change last line to

```
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
    C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
) Else (
    bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this solution works:

**File: git.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=%*
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
    C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
) Else (
    bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As *Gabrielizalo* answered earlier, you need to use version **2020.2** and higher.

- Go to **Settings | Version Control | Git**
- Add `\\wsl$\YOUR-WSL-VERSION\usr\bin\git` to the **Path to Git executable**
- Press **Test**

Please note, if you are using the **WLinux** distribution, you need to use the name **Pengwin**.
Even though the `wsl -l` command outputs the name as WLinux. Perhaps It will be fixed in future versions.

This is how it works for me `\\wsl$\Pengwin\usr\bin\git`.

If you are still having problems with Pengwin (WLinux). You need to reimport it as Pengwin.
Follow this instruction:

- Restart your system.
- Open PowerShell as administrator.
- `wsl --list`. You will see a list of distributions, including **WLinux (Default)**.
- Make a backup with command `wsl --export distro_name file_name.tar`.
  For example, `wsl --export WLinux E:\backup.tar`. It will take some time, as the distribution can reach several gigabytes.
- Make sure the backup is complete, then remove the distribution from WSL with the command `wsl --unregister WLinux`.
- Next, reimport the distribution with name Pengwin
  `wsl --import distro_name install_location file_name.tar`, e.g.,
  `wsl --import Pengwin C:\Users\<USERNAME>\pengwin E:\backup.tar`
- Set the distribution as default `wsl --setdefault Pengwin`
- To run default WSL distro as the specified user use `wsl --user <Username>`
- Add `\\wsl$\Pengwin\usr\bin\git` to the **Path to Git executable** to your IDE, and press **Test**

Note, now when using `pengwin` in cmd, or from the **Start menu**, a new Pengwin instance will be installed. You can check this with the `wsl --list` command. The new instance will show up as WLinux. If you accidentally create a new instance, you can delete it with the command `wsl --unregister WLinux`.

For the convenience of using your distro, I strongly recommend installing a custom terminal. You can follow this guide [How to setup a nice looking terminal with WSL in Windows 10](https://medium.com/@Andreas_cmj/how-to-setup-a-nice-looking-terminal-with-wsl-in-windows-10-creators-update-2b468ed7c326).

Comment: When using wsl1, you need to `Enable the git.allow.wsl1.executables option in IDE Registry (Help - FInd Action - Registry...)` as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242469 does

Answer (score 2):

Worked till PHPSTORM 2018.3 (or maybe a Windows Update changed some behavior regarding bash.exe). I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. However, the path of my bash.exe changed - it is no longer in `C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe`.

To get things working again I modified Elies Lou's wslgit.bat and set new path for bash.exe:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=%*
set find=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt
set replace=/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Temp/git-commit-msg-.txt
call set command=%%command:!find!=!replace!%%
echo | C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c 'git %command%'
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated the soultion to work with WSL2 with a network drive and PhpStorm 2019.2.

wsl_git.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set command=%*
set find=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt
set replace=/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Temp/git-commit-msg-.txt
call set command=%%command:!find!=!replace!%%
echo | wsl CURDIR="%cd%"; STR2=${CURDIR//\\//}; STR3=${STR2/U:/}; cd $STR3; git %command%
```

1. It replaces the path in `command` for `git-commit-msg-.txt` to be able to commit as it was mentioned in other answers.
2. With WSL2 I use the network drive: `\\wsl$\<distro_name>` -> `U:\`. My project has path on Windows: `U:\home\roman\projects\experiments`, but on Linux it is `/home/roman/projects/experiments`. PhpStorm uses path from Windows to work with git, so it is needed to change path which can be reachable in the Linux subsystem. To achieve this I replace slashes `\` -> `/` (`STR2`) and remove drive name `U:` -> `` (`STR3`) then change current dir to this modified path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install your project file in the wsl file system , any way you'll need this iff you go docker ;p
2. Open your project from \wsl$
3. (if needed) Go to Settings > Version Control > Git > and simply clear the Path to Git executable

and this work so fine !

Answer (score 0):

Since updating to 2022.3.3 I get this for my `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\git` path.
Which previously worked, and I've also seen it today even work sometimes but not other times.

```
Git is not installed
Cannot identify version of git executable: no response
```

It does take a while for my wsl to startup/respond when I open a new terminal for it for example, so maybe the timeout needs to be extended?